# SQL Where in query with "AND" in NHibernate

Tags: sql

As we know that the "Where In" sql query does an OR for the input.

Sorry I could not upload image.. so I have created how my db view looks like.
for example

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>RoomBlockDateID</td>
    <td>RoomBlockID</td>
    <td>AvailableDate</td>
    <td>PublicRemaining</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2105</td>
    <td>633</td>
    <td>2009-10-14 00:00:00:000</td>
    <td>0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2106</td>
    <td>633</td>
    <td>2009-10-15 00:00:00:000</td>
    <td>100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2107</td>
    <td>633</td>
    <td>2009-10-16 00:00:00:000</td>
    <td>150</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2108</td>
    <td>633</td>
    <td>2009-10-17 00:00:00:000</td>
    <td>100</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>2109</td>
    <td>635</td>
    <td>2009-10-14 00:00:00:000</td>
    <td>0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2110</td>
    <td>635</td>
    <td>2009-10-15 00:00:00:000</td>
    <td>70</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2111</td>
    <td>635</td>
    <td>2009-10-16 00:00:00:000</td>
    <td>90</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2112</td>
    <td>635</td>
    <td>2009-10-17 00:00:00:000</td>
    <td>0</td>
</tr>
```

Here is what I do

```
Select distinct RoomBlockID from Table where availabledate in ('10/14/2009', '10/15/2009', '10/16/2009') and PublicRemaining > 0
```

Then it will return RoomBlockID 631 and 633. But what I am looking for in my hotel booking system, that only if publicremaining is > 0 for all the given dates, then return the correct RoomBlockIDs. Looking at the above query, it will return none. But if I modify the query to

```
Select distinct RoomBlockID from Table where availabledate in ('10/15/2009', '10/16/2009', '10/17/2009') and PublicRemaining > 0
```

Then it will return 631 and not 633.

I can use a cursor and go though each Roomblockids and check if all required dates have remaining > 0 then return the RoomBlockID. But I want to know if there is a query to do so?

Please advise.
Thank you

Comment: What database is this (mysql, oracle, sql server, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your database supports the INTERSECT set operator (probably will unless you're using MySQL) you can use:

```
select roomblockid
  from table
 where availabledate = '10/15/2009'
   and PublicRemaining > 0
intersect
select roomblockid
  from table
 where availabledate = '10/16/2009'
   and PublicRemaining > 0
intersect
select roomblockid
  from table
 where availabledate = '10/17/2009'
   and PublicRemaining > 0
```

If not you can use:

```
Select RoomBlockID
  from Table
 where availabledate in ('10/15/2009', '10/16/2009', '10/17/2009')
   and PublicRemaining > 0
 group by RoomBlockID
having count(*) = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a count field, and use the `Having` Clause:

```
SELECT
  id,
  count(availableDate) as ct
FROM
  rooms
WHERE availableDate IN("2009-10-10","2009-10-11", "2009-10-12")
AND publicRemaining > 0
GROUP BY id
HAVING ct = 3
```

If you filter for 5 Elements and add the contion `ct = 5` - that ensures, that there is one entry
per day. (Assuming you only have one row per room and day)

This query returns 2 rooms possible: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a714e/7

for this, its only one room possible: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a714e/10

(the condition needs to match number of elements inside the `IN()` field)